# Combination of stacked and side-by-side bar charts in R

Tags: r, lattice

In the lattice package of R it is possible to create stacked bar charts. I would like to have several stacked bars side by side similar to this one:

```
barchart( mpg ~ as.factor(gear), data=mtcars, groups=cyl, stack=F, horizontal=F, auto.key=T )
```

[image: side-by-side barchart with covered bars]

This is almost what I need. The problem is that the bars are layered, e.g. for the pink bar at the center there are 3 layered bars of approximately the same value (between 17 and 22). The bars are not stacked. The bar that is painted later covers bars painted earlier.

Would it also be possible to have different colors/textures for the stacked bars as well as for the side-by-side bars and an additional legend? The different levels in the stack come from an additional factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image]
    mtcars$ID <- rownames(mtcars)
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl), group = ID)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_jitter()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the bars are still not stacked within a group. It is like having three factors: 1. factor(gear): groups of stacked bars 2. factor(cyl): bars within one group; each bar consists of several levels 3. another factor (e.g. carb from the mtcars data frame) to distinguish the levels within a stack of bars